# How to automate CQ5 using selenium?

Tags: selenium, bdd, aem

I trying to find some solution to automate test cq5 projects. 
I found some problems like: extjs is genrateing random values dynamically.
I want to use key driven approach and use stack selenium + cucumber.
If someone has experience in that, please give me some advices.

Comment: you can assign id's to the cq widgets in the dialog if you need to interact with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct Answer from adobe
by Sham HC on Oct 30, 2012 6:59 AM
Earlier version of CQ (5.4) had Basic Selenium test case shipped with product.  See if that helps

1) Download the File from your CQ5 Installation, e.g. /libs/wcm/testing/.zip
2) Unpack the zip on the same server where you installed a cq5 default author and publish
3) Navigate to the extracted directory and execute start.bat. This will start a selenium server and start the test runner
4) Make sure that CQ5 is running before starting the test and that Internet Explorer is available on the machine.